# How do peaceful muslims explain forbidance of fighting in sacred months?

Tags: quran, tafseer, jihad

I was under the impression that Islam allowed only defensive jihad and used to argue with non muslims that initiation is not to be done by muslims. Courtesy to zakir naik explaination. A random non muslim presented before me the hadith of bukhari which said "i have been sent with the sword". Investigation and subsequent search only yielded the opposite. **Intiative in war can be taken by a ruler only**.

Since its axiomatic that defence is permitted in sacred months, Dhul Hijjah(12th), Dhul Qadah (11th), Rajab (7th) and Muharram (1st).

The Question arises how do peaceful muslims explain Allah forbidding fighting in sacred months.

> Verily, the number of months with Allah is twelve months (in a year), so was it ordained by Allah on the Day when He created the heavens and the earth; of them **four are sacred**. That is the right religion, so wrong not yourselves therein, and **fight against the Mushrikin (idolaters) collectively** as they fight against you collectively. But know that Allah is with those who have Taqwa quran 9:36

Im asking this because i fear a verse from quran.

> And whoever opposes the Messenger after guidance has become clear to him and follows other than the way of the believers - **We will give him what he has taken and drive him into Hell**, and evil it is as a destination. Quran 4:115

Comment: Defensive Jihad? First of all this expression itself is self-contradictory. Secondly Allah wants Muslim to show strength and power. Jihad is done in order to save Muslim lives be it by attacking the enemy or defending Muslims. However of course Muslims should respect the 4 holy months and avoid fighting during them without an acceptable reason. Even if the abrogation of the ruling on the prohibition of fighting during them is a known dispute among scholars.

Answer (score -1):

9:36

> So do not wrong yourselves during them and fight the polytheists
> collectively, as they fight you collectively, and know that God is
> with the righteous.

may be understood in two ways in English - the understanding

«So do not wrong yourselves during them in that you are fighting the polytheists collectively»

must be wrong because then the word fight would need a negation in Arabic (ولا تقاتلوا).

It can only be understood in the sense:

«So do not wrong yourselves during them. (But as an exception) fight the polytheists  collectively as they do so as well.»

How do I as a peaceful Muslim explain that?

This Verse is given as an exception in the concrete situation of an active war. It does not abgrogate the general rule on a sacred month fighting should be avoided (more than during the other 8 months).

Comment: Then when the Sacred Months have passed, kill the idolators…) 9:5...https://www.google.com/amp/s/abdurrahman.org/2016/10/02/the-four-sacred-months-tafseer-ibn-kathir/amp/

Comment: @ShaikAbdullah a very good link with a good and comprehensive answer to your question. What else are you looking for?

Comment: I cant downvote because low points(below 125), why was your answer downvoted then?

Comment: @ShaikAbdullah I don't know why my answer was downvoted. I think it is in line with the answer you cited but not as comprehensive as it.